# stream creation with analytic module in spring-xd get failed

Tags: r, mqtt, spring-xd

[image]I am working on spring-xd framework. I am following Spring-XD guide Analytic tab and want to deploy my prediction model for live streaming data.

I have built the iris classification model using naive-Bayes in R and store that pmml file at my desktop in Ubuntu-14.0.4 Lts. this is my stream definition-

```
stream create test --definition "mqtt --url='tcp://localhost:1883' --topics='irisPayload'| analytic-pmml --location='/home/andy/Desktop/iris-flower-naive-bayes.pmml.xml' --inputFieldMapping='sepalLength:Sepal.Length,sepalWidth:Sepal.Width,petalLength:Petal.Length,petalWidth:Petal.Width'--outputFieldMapping='Predicted_Species:predictedSpecies' | file" --deploy
.
```

Error:- Analytic and processor module is not found.

I Think my stream definition is wrong. as I am unable to found stream definition for such a case in spring-xd guide.

I am running spring-xd in single-node at my local machine. Instead of Http, I want to send my data using MQTT Pub-Sub protocol. my MQTT broker is up and running, any sort of help is appreciated. thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you add the complete error and stack trace to your question?

Comment: @Gary, this is the error log-   Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Could not find module with name 'analytic-pmml' and type 'processor'.  after executing module list command , i didn't see analytics-pmml module. plz tell me how to add that module? and is my stream definition is correct?  thanks a lot, for always getting help from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, it's not distributed with XD out of the box because of licensing issues.

You can [find it on github here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-modules/tree/master/analytics-ml-pmml) and build/install it yourself.

Comment: after build /install steps, I had put the jar file in /xd/module/analytic-pmml directory. In module list now I am able to found analytic-pmml. this time I got following error-log: - Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Error with option(s) for module analytic-pmml of type processor: inputFieldMapping: option named 'inputFieldMapping' is not supported location: option named 'location' is not supported. is my stream definition is right?? I have edited the question by adding the image.

Comment: You put the jar in the wrong place, you should copy it as `.../modules/processor/analytic-pmml.jar` - then `module info --name processor:analytic-pmml` shows the available options. (I found this out by using `module upload ...` and found that it put the jar with that name in `custom-modules`). I updated the README.